# Inconsistent capitalization in site's description

Tags: discussion, bug

The [tour](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/tour) describes the site as follows:

> Data Science Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for Data science professionals, Machine Learning specialists, and those interested in learning more about the field.

Capitalizing "Data" but not "science" seems wrong. It should be either both or neither. Ideally, "Machine Learning" part would be consistent with that.

I suggest lowercasing it:

> a question and answer site for data science professionals, machine learning specialists, ....

which would be consistent with [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour), [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tour), and [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tour) — all of these sites use the lowercase form when the term is a part of a sentence.

Answer (score 6):

That's fine, I agree it should be consistent, and I think it should be Data Science. Now, if I only knew how to edit that text ...

Comment: For reference, this part of the Tour page is drawn from the site description, which is set by staff in the site settings. If the community wants it changed, someone should make a post on Meta to discuss whether it should be changed/what it should be changed to; once there's a consensus from the community on what it should be changed to, a mod can add the [status-review] tag to escalate it to the CMs, and then we can look at the discussion and have a dev implement the change if appropriate.